# DataGridView Validation - remove error indicator

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datagridview

I'm validating a DataGridView using the following code ...

```
void centreDataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (centreDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "code")
    {
        Regex codeRegex = new Regex("^[0-9]{5}[0-9A-Z]$");
        if (!codeRegex.IsMatch(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
            centreDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "error text here";
        }
    }
}

void centreDataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    centreDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = string.Empty;
}
```

This works, except that if I enter the new row and then leave it again without entering any data, the error warning icon remains visible in the new row selector. How can I clear it?

Based on the suggestions received so far, I've modified the above code as follows ...

```
void centreDataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (centreDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "code")
    {
        if (!(centreDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) || 
            (e.FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty))
        {
            Regex codeRegex = new Regex("^[0-9]{5}[0-9A-Z]$");
            if (!codeRegex.IsMatch(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
            {
                centreDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "error text here";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does solve the problem of the error indicator displaying beside the new row when no data has been entered. However, when I enter invalid data, in any row, no error indicator is shown when I move off the row for the first time after entering the invalid data. If I move off the row with the invalid data, then move back to it, then move off it again, then the error indicator is shown.

Answer (score 4):

OK I believe I've got it now. I set the ErrorText to an empty string at the start of the CellValidating event handler, instead of in the CellEndEdit event handler, as follows. This is basically a combination of all the suggestions received, so thanks everybody, it was all helpful.

```
void centreDataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    centreDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = string.Empty;
    if (centreDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "code")
    {
        if (!(centreDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) || 
            (e.FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty))
        {
            Regex codeRegex = new Regex("^[0-9]{5}[0-9A-Z]$");
            if (!codeRegex.IsMatch(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
            {
                centreDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "blah blah blah";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add check if validated row is a [`NewRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.isnewrow.aspx) and return if it is.

```
void centreDataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (centreDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
    {
        return; // do not validate row that has no values
    }
    if (centreDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "code")
    {
        Regex codeRegex = new Regex("^[0-9]{5}[0-9A-Z]$");
        if (!codeRegex.IsMatch(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
            centreDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "error text here";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That almost works, thanks for trying, but there is an undesirable side effect. With the addition of that code, if I enter an invalid value in the new row and then move down again into what is now the new new row, the error indicator is not displayed in the invalid row just entered, not until I move back off the new row again.

Comment: @BrendanReynolds Instead of ignoring all validation for the new row, only validate if `[code column] && (!IsNewRow || !e.FormattedValue.IsEmpty)`

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions so far. Still not quite there yet. See modified code added to original question above. (Couldn't post it in a comment because of space limitations).