# how to validated the row datagridview in c#

Tags: c#

I need to validate my stock receiving qty from ordering Qty in a grid view. Below is a working of my code but am getting error. Can anyone please suggest or figure out the error.

```
private void Guna2DataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, 
DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {

        Guna2DataGridView view = sender as Guna2DataGridView;
        GridColumn colUnitsInStock = view.Columns["UnitsInStock"];
        GridColumn colUnitsOnOrder = view.Columns["UnitsOnOrder"];

        double unitsInStock = Convert.ToDouble(view.GetRowCellValue(view.FocusedRowHandle, colUnitsInStock));
        double unitsOnOrder = Convert.ToDouble(view.GetRowCellValue(view.FocusedRowHandle, colUnitsOnOrder));
        if (unitsInStock < unitsOnOrder)
        {
            view.SetColumnError(colUnitsInStock, "The Units On Order value should be less than this value.");
            view.SetColumnError(colUnitsOnOrder, "This value should be less than the Units In Stock value.");
            view.SetColumnError(null, "Invalid data");
            e.Valid = false;
            e.ErrorText = "'Units On Order' and 'Units In Stock' values are not consistent.";
        }

    }
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ipB3.png)

Comment: `Below is a working of my code but am getting error`, what error? Can you please post stack trace etc. so we can further help you out? If it's in that image, please post the actual error and not just an image, some of us may not click links and or navigate outside of this post.

Comment: can you see the error I post the pic on it

Comment: acutaly i what to unit in Stock =< to uniton order in data grid view but this code give me error on 4 and 5 line of may code

Comment: Look into : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112844/datagridview-validation-remove-error-indicator

Comment: sir I don't think so this code will work on my code but I will try thank you

Comment: Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellvalidatingeventargs?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) for the `DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs` class; it doesn't have any of those properties you're trying to set (`e.Valid` and `e.ErrorText`). Where did you get those?

Comment: from datagridview Event